# Etymology of Acolyte

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, loanwords

Why is the Greek word *ἀκολουθος* borrowed into Latin as *acolythus* and not *acoluthus*? Compare *Θουκυδιδης* and *Thucydides*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/acolyte#etymonline_v_5056):

> early 14c., "inferior officer in the church," from Old French *acolite* or directly from Medieval Latin *acolytus* (**Late Latin *acoluthus***), from Greek *akolouthos* "following, attending on," as a noun, "a follower, attendant," literally "having one way," from a- "together with," copulative prefix (see a- (3)), + keleuthos "a way, road, path, course, journey," which is of unknown etymology. The word was in late Old English as *acolitus*, a Latin form; in early modern English a corrected form *acolythe* was used.

You actually have the word *acolutha* attested in [Quintillian's *Institutiones*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1002/1/62/24491-24496#62), so it's not quite correct to say that the Latin word is *acolythus*. Seems the change was Medieval Latin just being Medieval Latin. The language not only went through a number of sound changes, but also was prone to hyper-correction, which, given the substitution of -y- for -i-, this might be; else it could have also come from French instead. Seems it's not clear.

Comment: υ and ου are evil twins in both [ancient Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_phonology#Vowel_raising_and_fronting) and dialectal modern greek (e.g., άγκυρα  pronounced as άγκουρα in several dialects), so these shifts are not altogether surprising...

Comment: More υ and ου confusion in [modern Greek dialects](https://www.lit.auth.gr/sites/default/files/documents/corpus_simeiwsewn_ellinikis_glwssas_ii.pdf): άχυρα > άχουρα, λύκος> λούκο.

Answer (score 4):

Adapatation of Greek ου as **y** is certainly not expected.

I would guess that there may have been some analogical influence from other words ending in *-ytus,* perhaps *proselytus* from προσήλυτος.

It's also possible that the replacement of U with Y was based on scribal awareness of the fact that Classical Latin U sometimes does represent Greek υ, as in *murra* = μύρρα; thus, to someone with no direct knowledge of the original Greek spelling, the Latin spelling *acoluthus* (mentioned by cmw) is somewhat ambiguous evidence for whether the original Greek word had ου or υ.